# How to get the offset of a partition with a bash script?

Tags: bash, offset, mbr

I can use `parted` to find out the offset of my image.

```
sudo parted -s image.img unit B print
Model:  (file)
Disk /home/user/image.img: 107374182400B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start     End            Size           Type     File system  Flags
 1      2097152B  107374182399B  107372085248B  primary  ext4
```

For example, partition starts at `2097152`.

How can I get the `2097152` with a bash script?

I could probably parse the output, but perhaps there is a more suited method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option, feed the output to [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
sudo parted -s image.img unit B print | 
awk '/^Number/{p=1;next}; p{gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/, "", $2); print $2}'
```

Comment: this works great if there is only one partition, in case of multiple partition, it will print the start offset of each partition one by one

Answer (score 0):

In case of multiple partitions in the image and to get only the first partition offset, you can use the following :

```
sudo parted -s image.img unit B print | sed 's/^ //g' | grep "^1 " | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

- `sed` will remove leading space
- `grep` will extract line for partition 1 (change that number if you want another partition)
- `tr` will remove extra space between words
- final `cut` will extract the second number on the line which is the start offset