# Offset of a specific listed partition

Tags: bash, awk

Building off a question found here:
[How to get the offset of a partition with a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181695/how-to-get-the-offset-of-a-partition-with-a-bash-script) in regards to using awk,bash and parted for a GPT partition

Being pretty new to scripting languages I am not sure if and how to build off the existing request.

I am looking to grab a specific partition listed by the parted command. Specifically I need the start sector of the ntfs partition for setting a offset in mount within my bash script.

```
root@workstation:/mnt/ewf2# parted ewf1 unit B p
Model:  (file)
Disk /mnt/ewf2/ewf1: 256060514304B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start End Size File system  Name Flags
 1  1048576B    525336575B     524288000B   fat32  EFI system partition  boot
 2  525336576B  659554303B     134217728B          Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3  659554304B  256060162047B  255400607744B ntfs  Basic data partition    msftdata
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep` with PCRE:

```
parted ewf1 unit B p | grep -Po "^\s+[^ ]+\s+\K[^ ]+(?=\s.*ntfs)"
```

**Output:**

```
659554304B
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk`is your friend for this task:

```
$ parted ewf1 unit B p |awk '$5=="ntfs"{print $2}'
```

When the 5th column equals `ntfs`, print the second one.

Answer (score 1):

This will print the second field of the last line:

```
parted ewf1 unit B p | awk 'END { print $2  }'  # prints 659554304B
```

or you can search for a line that matches `ntfs`

```
parted ewf1 unit B p | awk '/ntfs/ { print $2  }'  # prints 659554304B
```